# Length error using D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, typeerror

So I am pretty new to js and D3 and I am keep getting this error in my code. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on line 1 of d3.min.js. Here is my code:

```
    d3.csv("ExecutedOffenders.csv", function(csv) {
  //racial demographics graph
  var height=700;
  var width=700;
  var newHeight=350;
  var newWidth=350;
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

  yearMap = [];

  years = _.map(_.range(1982,2015),function(n){return n.toString()});

  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    if ((years.indexOf((parseDate(csv[i].date)).getFullYear().toString()) >= 0) == false) {
      years.push((parseDate(csv[i].date)).getFullYear().toString());
    }
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    yearObject = {};
    yearObject.year = years[i];
    yearObject.count = (_.filter(csv, function(execution) { return (parseDate(execution.date)).getFullYear().toString() === years[i]})).length
    yearMap.push(yearObject);
  }

  countMap = _.map(yearMap, function(obj) {
    return obj.count;
  });
  console.log(countMap);

  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,yearMap.length]).range([0,width/1.2]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(countMap)]).range([height/2,0]);



  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(_.range(0,yearMap.length))
    .tickFormat(function(d){
      return yearMap[d].year;
    });

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return x(yearMap.indexOf(d));})
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.count);});

  var lineGraph = d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg")
    .attr("width",700)
    .attr("height",450)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(30,30)");

  x.domain([0,yearMap.length]);
  y.domain([0,d3.max(countMap)]);

  lineGraph.selectAll("circle")
    .data(yearMap)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",function(d){return x(yearMap.indexOf(d));})
    .attr("cy",function(d){return y(d.count);})
    .attr("r",3)
    .attr("transform","translate(20,0)");

  lineGraph.selectAll("text")
    .data(yearMap)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.count;
    })
    .attr("x",function(d) {
      return x(yearMap.indexOf(d));
    })
    .attr("y",function(d) {
      return y(d.count);
    })
    .attr("transform","translate(20,-10)")
    .style("font-size","9px")
    .style("fill","red");

  lineGraph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,350)")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor","end")
      .attr("dx","-.8em")
      .attr("dy",".15em")
      .attr("transform","translate(-5,0) rotate(-90)");

  lineGraph.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform","translate(20,0)")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Executions");

  lineGraph.append("path")
      .datum(yearMap)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform","translate(20,0)");

console.log(yearMap)
});
```

This is my HTML structure

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<div id="svgContainer"></div>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Is there some code you left out or is this the first place `years` is defined? `years = _.map(_.range(1982, 2015), function (n) { return n.toString() });`

Comment: No. I am using underscore js. Here: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't put `var` in front of `years`?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen That's not entirely important, it will make it a global variable, but wont cause an error.

Comment: My guess is that `csv.length` is not working, because the csv is not an Array. You may want to find a new way to determine that.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen That was my first thaught as well, because if an error occurs, `csv` will be `null`. But the error message reads `undefined` instead of `null` and the source is in d3.min.js. I suppose the error occurs earlier while loading.

Comment: @AnasAshraf Could you provide an extract of your input file or set up a live example to fiddle around with?

Comment: Take a look at the stacktrace in Chrome devtools or something and find what line of your code was calling a d3 function when the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

[d3.csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) expects a callback function with the following signature:

```
d3.csv(url, function(error, data) {
  // if error is "truthy", data will be undefined
  // otherwise, the inverse is true
});
```

Note that the error is the *first* parameter. I think what's happening is that your CSV is loading correctly, so your `csv` variable is actually `null` because there was no error. You can confirm this by:

1. using the Chrome (or similar) dev tools to set a breakpoint inside your callback function and inspect the `csv` variable; or
2. inserting a `console.log(arguments)` as the first statement your callback function and seeing what shows up in the console.